# Searching for locations (city names), displaying on map (Android)

Tags: android

I am creating an app, and want to app to allow users to search for locations of things, display them in a list, then display the address on a map.

I have the app listing cities..would the display of the address on a map be constructed using a fragment?

Thanks so much--trying to plan how to do this. Using Parse as my backend.

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have listing cities, and that city have some info for example *name**,description* , *address*, *zip code* etc.. then pass it using **Bundle** and setText the address if you have textview on the map

Comment: this answer does not make any sense